# How to post music files to sql database in php?

Tags: php

I'm having a problem trying to upload music files to my sql database. I'm getting an Notice: Array to string conversion. This has to do with line `$trackname = basename("$files");` The column trackname always says array. How could I change this to all the musicfiles ending in .wav?

```
<?php
// Make connection with database
$con = mysqli_connect("*******");

//Func to check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  printf("Connection failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
}


// Scan Directory for files
$files = glob('*.wav');


usort ($files, function($a, $b) {
  return filemtime($a) < filemtime($b);
});

//insert list of files to database IF they dont exist

foreach ($files as $file) {
  $trackname = basename("$files");
  echo $trackname."**";
  $addquery = "INSERT INTO song (id, trackname, year, numlikes, numplays) VALUES (default, '$trackname', '2020', '0', '0')";
  mysqli_query($con, $addquery);
  $files++;
  }


  ?>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want to use basename("$file"), not basename("$files") in your foreach.

Comment: WOW! I feel so stupid. THANK YOU @Yishmeray!!!!!!!!